# Edit StatusBar's frame

Tags: ios, frame, statusbar, uiwindow, uistatusbar

I would like to access the StatusBar's frame and change it(to have more space to display another control in the horizontal way since the space on the Navigation Bar on the iPhone is pretty limited).

Is this possible through some kind of manipulation through the StatusBar's UIWindow or absolutely impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on iOS. You can try replicating the status bar on your own, or lose it all together.

Answer (score 1):

You can custom StatusBar only changing its color.
But if you don't want it, you can hide StatusBar.